# How to tell selenium to use test database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, testing, selenium

I'm using selenium-client to run a few tests, but Selenium seems to be using my development database.  How can I point it to use my test DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to point Selenium to a site that uses the test databases. Selenium talks to your rails, not the database. So, you need to point Selenium to a web app whose config points to your test db, not the dev db.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to point the Selenium test at an instance of your app that uses the test database.

I wrote a separate deploy task in my capistrano deploy.rb that deploys the application to a testing server, points it at the test db, and loads the selenium-specific fixtures. Selenium treats a deployed app as a black box, so it's up to you to fit all that in to your existing deployment setup.